# Are Backus–Naur Form (BNF) and Extended Backus–Naur Form metalanguages or metasyntax?

Tags: grammar-formalism

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_Form

> Extended Backus–Naur Form (EBNF) is a family of metasyntax notations,
>   any of which can be used to express a context-free grammar.

Does it mean that a context-free grammar is a metalanguage of a context-free language, and EBNF is a syntax for the context-free grammar as a metalanguage, and therefore EBNF is a metasyntax for the context-free language as a object language?

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntax

> A metasyntax describes the allowable structure and composition of
>   phrases and sentences of a metalanguage, which is used to describe
>   either a natural language or a computer programming language.
>
> Some of the widely used formal metalanguages for computer languages
>   are Backus–Naur Form (BNF), Extended Backus–Naur Form (EBNF), Wirth
>   syntax notation (WSN), and Augmented Backus–Naur Form (ABNF).

Does it mean that EBNF is a metalanguage of  a context-free grammar being a formal language?

---

Some relevant definitions:

From https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Syntax

> The syntax of a formal language is its structure, and is specified by
>   a formal grammar of the formal language.

From https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Metalanguage

> A metalanguage of a formal language is a formal language used to specify the formal language (make statements about the formal language).
>
> The object language of a metalanguage is the language described by that metalanguage.

From https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Metalanguage/Metasyntax

> The syntax of a metalanguage is called a metasyntax of the object
>   language of that metalanguage.

Comment: It's not a language, you can't make propositions in it.

Comment: what are BNF and EBNF then?

Comment: Notations. Metasyntaxes possibly, I don't know what that term is used for.

Comment: For a formal language, are its formal grammar and its syntax the same thing?

Comment: @Tim: Yes. People who talk about formal languages as if they really existed always use the word _syntax_ to mean 'grammar'.

Comment: But a formal language may not have a formal grammar that can generate it. Still syntax should exist, so what is its formal definition?@jlawler

Comment: @Tim, formal languages (CLs, at least) have semantics as well, so specifying the syntax is not sufficient to *define* a language.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia definition of a [metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage), a metalanguage is a language used to make statements about statements in another language. That is, it is a language designed to describe the constructs of another language.

Wikipedia then defines a [metasyntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntax) as the syntax or grammar of a given metalanguage.

Therefore, Backus-Naur Form (BNF) is a metalanguage which defines a metasyntax (i.e. a metagrammar) that you use to write statements in BNF to describe the constructs in another language.